# How to overlay lat and long datapoints on top of plotly geojson map

Tags: plotly, geojson

geojson map downloaded from here:
https://github.com/codeforgermany/click_that_hood/blob/main/public/data/ireland-counties.geojson

code example from here: https://community.plotly.com/t/scatter-geo-change-map/36055/4

```
import geojson
import plotly.graph_objects as go

with open("data/ireland-counties.geojson") as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

pts = []
for feature in gj['features']:
    if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Polygon':
        pts.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0])    
        pts.append([None, None])#mark the end of a polygon   
        
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
        for polyg in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
            pts.extend(polyg[0])
            pts.append([None, None])#end of polygon
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'LineString': 
        points.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
        points.append([None, None])
    else: pass           
    #else: raise ValueError("geometry type irrelevant for map")

x, y = zip(*pts)    

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines', line_color='#999999', line_width=1.5)
fig.update_layout(width=600,  height=800)
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly map]

I want to overlay this metadata and coordinates onto the existing map:

```
metadata = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['AH1','AH2','DO20','DO25','TI1','TI2'],
             'Latitude':[52.457079,52.457674,52.722615,52.724745,51.616257,51.616090],
             'Longitude':[-9.309839,-9.309434,-9.500108,-9.499674,-8.806805,-8.805225]})
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(...))` to add the latitude and longitude from the metadata as another trace:

```
import geojson
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

with open("ireland-counties.geojson") as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

pts = []
for feature in gj['features']:
    if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Polygon':
        pts.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0])    
        pts.append([None, None])#mark the end of a polygon   
        
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
        for polyg in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
            pts.extend(polyg[0])
            pts.append([None, None])#end of polygon
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'LineString': 
        points.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
        points.append([None, None])
    else: pass           
    #else: raise ValueError("geometry type irrelevant for map")

x, y = zip(*pts)    

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines', line_color='#999999', line_width=1.5)
fig.update_layout(width=600,  height=800)

metadata = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['AH1','AH2','DO20','DO25','TI1','TI2'],
             'Latitude':[52.457079,52.457674,52.722615,52.724745,51.616257,51.616090],
             'Longitude':[-9.309839,-9.309434,-9.500108,-9.499674,-8.806805,-8.805225]})

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=metadata['Longitude'],
        y=metadata['Latitude'],
        mode='markers'
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]